How to create fallback URL for opening facebook link in app via JavaScript?
I'm using fb://profile/id (which apparently works both for IOS and Android) to open a facebook profile in the app rather than the browser.
However, I also need a fallback to a browser address in case the app isn't installed.
Any suggestions on how to implement this in JavaScript?
